# Suggested edits on duplicate tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, review, suggested-edits

I was asked to [review](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/163289) an edit on a tag which has only a single question. Turns out it is a duplicate tag because both [regex](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/regex) and [regexp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/regexp) exist. Should I approve an edit to create a description on a duplicate tag, or should I reject the edit explaining that a merge is more appropriate?

Secondly, how could I get those two tags merged? Apparently I don't have sufficient reputation to even suggest that the tags get merged (either that or I don't know how to do it). I tried suggesting regexp as a synonym for regex, but I am not allowed to suggest that.

Comment: In all cases where you see tags that should be merged just drop them in a Question on meta. We'll clean it up. The official method of suggesting tag synonyms doesn't work on a site smaller than [So]. And there isn't enough volume to bother with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a case like this, you should bring the tags to meta so that we can do this:

[regexp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/regexp) has been merged into [regex](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/regex) and synonymized. Enjoy!